# sparx Enterprise Architect BPMN step/navigate into and back out of child models (composite models)

Tags: enterprise-architect

In BPMN 2, I can select a child composite diagram from another BPMN model package. I can also then navigate INTO this diagram from the parent diagram by clicking on the "+" sign in the parent activity. However

I can't find a way to directly navigate back to the diagram that I came from. Where is the "back" button?

Registered Enterprise Architect (Professional Edition) 14.0.1421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just close the newly opened composite diagram and you're back. No other way. This is EA...

Comment: Thanks, and yes, will separate.